# Hibernate OneToMany children and cascading

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have what is becoming a pretty complex entity setup:

A -> (one-to-one, share same primary key) B -> (one-to-many) C

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private A a;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Set<C> c;
}  

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long cId;

    @MapsId
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("id")
    private B b;
}
```

I want to create A, B, and C at the same time. First of all, is this possible? Real quick unit test:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

C c1 = new C();
c1.setB(b);
C c2 = new C();
c2.setB(b);

Set<C> set = new HashSet<C>(2);
set.add(c1);
set.add(c2); // works if this is commented out

b.setA(a);
b.setC(set);

a.setB(b);

crudRepo.save(a);
```

`DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

I have tried a whole load of combinations with different cascade types, different "ownedBys" and either end up with it trying to generate multiple "C"s with the same ID/primary key, or an error saying C needs to be persisted first. Apologies if I copied over some code incorrectly - tried to keep the irrelevant stuff out.

Comment: The field `private B b;`  in class `B` looks strange. Is it reference to itself?

Comment: Crap, I knew I would screw something up! Should be `A` - edited

Comment: Your mapping also assume that your table related to the entity `C` should have `c_id` and `id` column - foreign key to the `B` table. Is it true?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to correct your mapping in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    // ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
    private A a;
}
```

and then save your entities in this way:

```java
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c1 = new C();
C c2 = new C();

Set<C> set = new HashSet<C>(2);
set.add(c1);
set.add(c2);

b.setC(set);

// sync both side of bi-directional @OneToOne association
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a)

crudRepo.save(a);
```

Comment: Thank you, your changes make sense to me. I added bi-directional association with everything. I am still getting:
`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [C#1]`

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I also would suggest you to explicitly specify what [GenerationType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators) you want to use (IDENTITY or SEQUENCE) and not rely on hibernate [choice](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto).

Comment: WOW! I think my issue was mainly the `MapsID` on `C` which I must have foolishly pasted. Perhaps that and a combination of specifying GenerationType. Thank you for all of your help!